# how to create medium text filed in mysql using django models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a django model and used TextField for one of the attributes of the model. but when i look into the MYSQL table structure it is created as long text. How can i speify django to create a medium text filed.
my model structure:

```
class ModelExample(models.Model):
    AdditionalReqFields=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: what is the maximum length of your strings?

Comment: i thought medium text will be the best for this column as long text consumes more space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you can't.

In longer, if a `CharField` (backed by `VARCHAR`) is suitable, that's an option, or create your own subclass of `TextField` and override the `db_type(self, connection)` method.

See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_type

Comment: what will happen if manually alter the column type in mysql DB?

Comment: I don't know enough about the differences between MySQL's handling of the column types to say, sorry. BUT, that could possibly be ok.

Comment: it works if you manually atler the column type. Better solution though: `class MediumTextField(models.Field):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'MEDIUMTEXT'`

Answer (score 0):

The `django-mysql` package includes a `SizedTextField` that you can set to use `MEDIUMTEXT`.

https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/resizable_text_binary_fields.html?highlight=mediumtext#django_mysql.models.SizedTextField

For example:

```py
from django_mysql.models.fields import SizedTextField

AdditionalReqFields = SizedTextField(size_class=3, null=True, blank=True)
```